# What are these mobile pixels?

Tags: reverse-engineering, touchscreen, mobile, pixels

I've got this picture under my microscope for an old Samsung Galaxy Ace mobile phone, I'd like to know what are the different pixels in the rows with a **separation** in the subpixels? And how are they different from the regular ones in the adjacent rows? I've tried searching for the exact circuit implementation of mobile phone touch screens but sadly didn't reach an answer.

[image: pixels]

Comment: It might be a little easier to understand if there was a picture with just a single subpixel illuminated so that the subpixel boundaries could be seen.  My guess from looking at it is that the pixels are roughly square, so all subpixels in that image are identical and the two row structure is part of one pixel.  It is hard to know from that image however.

Comment: Is it possible you're seeing the touch-panel on top of the pixel grid?

Comment: @user1850479 Yes! I've saw it again with a black image with a white dot in the middle and found that these are the boundaries of one pixel, I've updated the image.

Comment: @Orotavia I'm really not sure about that, but probably yes since I'm not choosing to see something specific of the screen layers.